# Practising on creating functions and passing params | Getting null when trying to use params on querySelectors

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, queryselector

I'm newbie in Javascript, I was practising with functions & params and I "hit a wall" when tried to use functions to do some changes in DOM, by passing params in those functions that would do the job.
in the browser's console I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
classAdder script.js:25
<anonymous> script.js:48
```

25th line is the line inside the classAdder function and 48th is the calling of classAdder.

Thank you in advance.

```
// Function decleration
function createArticle(h1, p) {
  let art = document.createElement("article");
  let data = document.createTextNode("<h1>" + [h1] + "</h1><p>" + [p] + "</p>");
  art.appendChild(data);
  return art;
}

// Arrow Function
const byTagElementAdder = (whereadd, whatadd) => {
  document.getElementsByTagName(CSS.escape(whereadd)).innerHTML = whatadd;
};

// Function expression
const classAdder = function (element, classname) {
  document
    .querySelector(CSS.escape(element))
    .setAttribute("class", CSS.escape(classname));
};

// Arrow function
const styleAdder = (element, style) => {
  document
    .querySelector(CSS.escape(element))
    .setAttribute("style", CSS.escape(style));
};

//
// Using the functions
// Creating new article
const firstArt = createArticle(
  "The H title",
  "The paragraph lorem ipsum bla bla"
);

// adding article in body
byTagElementAdder("body", firstArt);

// adding some style and class
classAdder(firstArt, "art");
styleAdder(firstArt, "width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 2rem 0 ;");
```

Comment: What is `CSS.escape` and what does it return?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList, not a single element. Assigning to its `innerHTML` has no effect, you need to loop over all the elements, or index it with `[0]` to get the first match.

Comment: `classAdder()` and `styleAdder()` expect the argument to be a selector for an element. But you're passing the element itself, not a selector.

Comment: And `byTagElementAdder()` expects `whatadd` to be an HTML string, but you're passing an element.

Comment: All in all, you're mixing up DOM elements, CSS selectors, and HTML strings.

Comment: @superjisan 's changes worked! I also tried to use .querySelector instead of .getElementByTagName and it worked perfectly. in addition I tried to remove all CSS.escape() from the code, again worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things I changed to make your code work:

1. The reason you are getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null` is because you are using `CSS.escape` which needs a string but you are passing in the dom element. So you can just use `.setAttribute` right on the element.
2. Your `byTagElementAdder` function was trying to insert innerHTML to an array. I've switched it to reference the first element of the array and use `appendChild` function instead
3. In your `createArticle` function, you are using a `createTextNode` but I think you would want to use `creatElement` for the `h1` and `p1` tag as you did for the article element.

Here's a code snippet

```js
function createArticle(h1, p) {
  let art = document.createElement("article");
    // this creates text as opposed to the h1 and p elements, which is what I think yu want  
  let data = document.createTextNode("<h1>" + [h1] + "</h1><p>" + [p] + "</p>");
  art.appendChild(data);
  return art;
}

// Arrow Function
const byTagElementAdder = (whereadd, whatadd) => {
    // getElementsByTagName returns an array so you want to choose a value within it
  document.getElementsByTagName(CSS.escape(whereadd))[0].appendChild(whatadd)
};

// Function expression
const classAdder = function (element, classname) {
    //once you pass in an element you don't need to use document.querySelector, you already have the document   
  element
    .setAttribute("class", CSS.escape(classname));
};

// Arrow function
const styleAdder = (element, style) => {
  //once you pass in an element you don't need to use document.querySelector, you already have the document 
  element
    .setAttribute("style", CSS.escape(style));
};

//
// Using the functions
// Creating new article
const firstArt = createArticle(
  "The H title",
  "The paragraph lorem ipsum bla bla"
);

// adding article in body
byTagElementAdder("body", firstArt);

// adding some style and class
classAdder(firstArt, "art");
styleAdder(firstArt, "width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 2rem 0 ;");
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, those changes worked!
I also tried to use .querySelector instead of .getElementByTagName and it worked perfectly.
in addition I tried to remove all CSS.escape() from the code, again worked perfectly.